# AWS Lambda のアップロードファイルの上限が 156MB に下がった？

Tags: aws-lambda

serverless で lambda をデプロイしたところ、以下のエラーが出るようになりました。

```
CREATE_FAILED: AppLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 156440758 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: e9bf6bXXXXX)" (RequestToken: 9253XXXXXXXXXX, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

アップロードのファイルの上限は 256MB だったと思うのですが、156MB に下がったのでしょうか？
情報を見つけられず、困っています。
だれか情報をお持ちではないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 環境

- Runtime は Python 3.11
- serverless: 3.35.2
- aws-cli: 1.29.10
- NodeJS: v18.18.0

Answer (score 0):

[Lambda デプロイパッケージ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html)には

> デプロイパッケージのサイズが 50 MB を超える場合は、関数のコードと依存関係を Amazon S3 バケットにアップロードしてください。

とあります。S3にアップロードされていますでしょうか？

Comment: serverless.yml の provider > deploymentBucket に指定した bucket に、zip 圧縮されたパッケージと CloudFormation に関するファイルが格納されています。
こちらからバケット経由で Lambda にデプロイされていると考えていましたが、認識あってますかね？

Comment: serverless.yml にて layer で pillow パッケージを読み込んでいる箇所を削除したらエラーが発生しなくなりました。
156MB 以上で〜 のエラーの理由はよくわかりません。。